# One sided limit of a composite function

Tags: limits

Suppose I wish to evaluate a limit of the form:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} g\left(f\left(x\right)\right)
$$

Where:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{y\to0^+} g\left(y\right) & = a \\
\lim_{y\to0^-} g\left(y\right) & = b \\
a & \neq b
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

And $f\left(x\right)$ approaches $0$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+ $. How do I determine whether $f\left(x\right)$ approaches $0$ from the positive or negative direction?

For example, I could demonstrate that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$
f\left(x\right) \geq 0 
$$

Which, I think, implies that $f\left(x\right) \rightarrow 0^+$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+ $, hence my original limit:
$$\lim_{x\to0^+} g\left(f\left(x\right)\right) = a$$

Alternatively, I could demonstrate that $\frac{\delta f\left(x\right)}{\delta x} > 0$ for $x > 0$, **and** $\frac{\delta f\left(x\right)}{\delta x} < 0$ for $x < 0$, which produces the same result.

Suppose I could only demonstrate this second property in the immediate neighborhood of $0$, for example: $|x| < \epsilon$ where $\epsilon > 0$. Does the conclusion still hold?

Comment: By MVT you will then have $f(x) >0$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)<0$ for $x>0$ in that neighborhood.